# XML Deserialization in List

Tags: c#, list, deserialization

Ok i have an Xml file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
   <Book>
     <Name>book name</Name>
     <Url>book url</Url>
     <Genre>book genre</Genre>
     <City>book city</City>
     <Country>book country</Country>
   </Book>
   <Book>
     <Name>book name</Name>
     <Url>book url</Url>
     <Genre>book genre</Genre>
     <City>book city</City>
     <Country>book country</Country>
   </Book>
   <Book>
     <Name>book name</Name>
     <Url>book url</Url>
     <Genre>book genre</Genre>
     <City>book city</City>
     <Country>book country</Country>
   </Book>
</Books>
```

And i want to use `Deserialization` in order to fill a `List` with books.
I have a class like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class Book
{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And a `List` like this :

```
List<Book> BookList;
```

I try to read from the xml File like this :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Book.xml", FileMode.Open);

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs))
{
   BookList.Add((Book)serializer.Deserialize(reader));
   reader.Close();
}
```

But i get an error in Xml File whenever i run my app. If i change my xml file to this :

```
<Book>
   <Name>book name</Name>
   <Url>book url</Url>
   <Genre>book genre</Genre>
   <City>book city</City>
   <Country>book country</Country>
</Book>
```

everything goes fine , expect that i only read 1 book. What i want to do is read around 100 books. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading from `FileStream` that we can read from `XmlDataDocument` and iteration of the book element will give us a serialization pretty much easier. Please take a look at the modified approach.

```
List<Book> BookList = new List<Book>();

            XmlDataDocument objDocument = new XmlDataDocument();
            objDocument.Load(@"Book.xml");


            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));                

            foreach(XmlNode objItem in   objDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                TextReader objTextReader = new StringReader(objItem.OuterXml);

                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(objTextReader))
                    {
                        BookList.Add((Book)serializer.Deserialize(reader));
                        reader.Close();
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

if you change your deserialization code a little bit, it will work.

(See the usage of `XmlRootAttribute` & and type `Book[]`)

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book[]),new XmlRootAttribute("Books"));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Book.xml", FileMode.Open);

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs))
{
    var books = (Book[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

*BTW: you don't need `Serializable` attribute, It is only used by [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)*

*PS: You can also use the type `List<Book>` instead of `Book[]`*

**EDIT**

After modifiying your code a little bit more, It can be as simple as:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Book>),
                                              new XmlRootAttribute("Books"));

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Book.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    List<Book> books = (List<Book>)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that @I4V's code fixes also the problem OP _would encounter_ further because of the `reader.Close();` instruction inside using statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that will contains a list of books and seriazlie this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class BookData
{
  [XmlArray(ElementName="Books")]
  [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Book")]
  public List<Book> Books {get; set;}

}
```

and then create the serializer like this:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BookData));
```